# AS3: why is this happening?

Tags: actionscript, garbage-collection

I just encounter a strange problem:

```
var a:ClassA = new ClassA;
var b:ClassA = a;
```

The program keeps running sometime, the a = null, b = null.

The program is a complex one, I am sure that no part will touch a, and b. My question is, will  the runtime(garbage collector) to collect the memory of "a" and then assign a and b to null?

I am confused, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector will reclaim the memory that this instance of `ClassA` occupies, only once there is no longer a reference to it.  As long as `a` OR `b` references that memory location, the instance will remain.  If these are local variables, then the instance will be picked up by the GC at some point after the function/method exits.  If those are instance variables then they will remain until after the defining class' instance is collected.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var a:ClassA = new ClassA();
var b:ClassA = a;
```

The () at the end of the class name calls the constructor so that you actually have your ClassA.